# Typeset chapters based on conditional settings

Tags: chapters, input, include

**Problem:**

Currently I like to work on each chapter by using `\iffalse` and `\fi` to skip processing certain chapters. But I am interested to know if there is a way to generalize this so one or more chapters can be turned off using true/false values.

**Example:**

- Chapter 1 = off
- Chapter 2 = on
- Chapter 3 = off
- Chapter 4 = off
- Chapter 5 = on

The above should only typeset chapter 2 and 5, while skipping the rest.

I am aware that I could use `\include`or `\input` to solve this issue by linking chapter/section files to the main file, but I am more interested to know if this could be done by using true/false settings in the preamble.

**Question:**

How could I restructure chapters/content to be shown/hidden during typesetting by using true/false (or other) values in the preamble?

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
 
\begin{document}
 
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Background}
\lipsum[2-4]

\iffalse

\chapter{Methodology}
\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Results and analysis}
\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Discussion}
\lipsum[2-4]

\fi

\chapter{Conclusions}
\lipsum[2-4]
 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a conditional for each chapter then just flip `true` or `false` in the preamble as required

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
 
\newif\ifintro
\newif\ifbackround
\newif\ifmethodology
\newif\ifresults
\newif\ifdiscussion
\newif\ifconclusions

\introtrue
\backroundtrue
\methodologyfalse
\resultsfalse
\discussiontrue
\conclusionsfalse

\begin{document}
 
\ifintro
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]
\fi

\ifbackround
\chapter{Background}
\lipsum[2-4]
\fi

\ifmethodology
\chapter{Methodology}
\lipsum[2-4]
\fi

\ifresults
\chapter{Results and analysis}
\lipsum[2-4]
\fi

\ifdiscussion
\chapter{Discussion}
\lipsum[2-4]
\fi

\ifconclusions
\chapter{Conclusions}
\lipsum[2-4]
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: of course this means chapter numbering changes as you skip different chapters and that `\ref` to omitted sections will not work, `\include` is designed to solve both these problems.